# Rabbit MQ connection is getting timed out with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, messagebroker

When try to connect Rabbit MQ instance running on seperate host/port , getting this exception that is more related to restarting of consumer and getting timed out

```html
2020-08-22 10:23:25.189  INFO [events-to-slack,,,] 1057 --- [an)#6c74acb-100] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2020-08-22 10:23:25.203 ERROR [events-to-slack,,,] 1057 --- [an)#6c74acb-110] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1370)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1346)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:336)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$800(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:99)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

I'm using spring boot 1.5.18. with Java 1.8

These are my configurations setup for rabbit-mq , here we can see that it's simply using topic exchange and tying to setup a listener with Queue bind with it

```
 @RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfiguration implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {

    private final Config configuration;
    private final RetryConfiguration retryConfig;

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(configuration.getExchange());
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange delayExchange() {
        TopicExchange topicExchange = new TopicExchange(configuration.getDelayExchange());
        topicExchange.setDelayed(true);
        return topicExchange;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(configuration.getQueue());
    }

    @Bean
    public List<Binding> bindings(@Qualifier("exchange") TopicExchange exchange,
            @Qualifier("delayExchange") TopicExchange delayExchange,
            @Qualifier("queue") Queue queue) {
        List<Binding> binding = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String routingKey : configuration.getRoutingKeys()) {
            binding.add(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingKey));
            binding.add(BindingBuilder.bind(queue)
                    .to(delayExchange)
                    .with(retryConfig.getPrefix() + routingKey));
        }
        return binding;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2MessageConverter consumerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory() {
        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
        factory.setMessageConverter(consumerJackson2MessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar endpointRegistrar) {
        endpointRegistrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory());
    }
```

Comment: Does it work at all? It looks it fails on the initial connection, so probably you have the wrong connection details configured (pointing to the wrong host/port?) or the rabbitMQ instance might have a firewall ... or it's not configured to listen on the right network interface.

Comment: Rabbit MQ instance does work when got connected with spring integration (i mean xml based configs ) , but when tries with annotation based config got error , what i don't understand the error message "Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s)" is it related to Queue if defined or related to rabbit-mq configs. i did updated question as well with the configs i defined.

Comment: @Augusto these are my rabbit-mq configs , i'm using in properties file 
spring.rabbitmq.host=*****
spring.rabbitmq.port=****
spring.rabbitmq.username=***
spring.rabbitmq.password=****
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=****
spring.rabbitmq.template.reply-timeout=10
spring.rabbitmq.template.receive-timeout=10
spring.rabbitmq.connection-timeout=10